# How can I move the view up for last text field when keyboard appears?

Tags: ios, swift, view, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a view inside that I have 6 text fields but I want to move up the view when click on last text field that I can Enter value in  last text field.

Here is my code but it is working for all text fields :-

```
 func animateViewMoving (up:Bool, moveValue :CGFloat){

    let movementDuration:TimeInterval = 0.3
    let movement:CGFloat = ( up ? -moveValue : moveValue)

    UIView.beginAnimations("animateView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)

    self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

So for particular textField how can I move the view up (Keyboard size)

Thanks

Comment: You can use autolayout?

Comment: You can use IQKeyboardManager for this issue.

Comment: Hey, better to use IQKeyBoardManager. It will take care of scrolling the views itself.

Comment: IQKeyBoardManager is a library ?

Comment: @kishor0011 yes it is library.

Comment: But I don't want to use library.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
var textFieldActive:UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Keyboard notification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown),name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow,
                                                     object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide),name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
                                                     object: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField){

    textFieldActive = textField
}



// MARK: - Keyboard notification Method
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
{
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardSize = (userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    let contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize?.height)!+100,  0.0)
    self.scrollViewGroupMakeTakers.contentInset = contentInset
    self.scrollViewGroupMakeTakers.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset

    // Step 3: Scroll the target text field into view.
    var aRect: CGRect = self.contentViewMakeTakers.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= (keyboardSize?.height)!+100
    if (!aRect.contains(textFieldActive!.frame.origin))
    {

        let scrollPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: textFieldActive!.frame.origin.y - (keyboardSize!.height-150));            
self.scrollViewGroupMakeTakers.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
    }
}
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification)
{
    let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    scrollViewGroupMakeTakers.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollViewGroupMakeTakers.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Comment: @kishor0011 if you found this as your answer. accept it as answer

Comment: I mean its not working for last text field.
It is working for all text fields.
Thanks

Comment: @kishor0011 Means you need only for last textField right?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this-**

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

     if textField == lastTextField{

            view.frame.origin.y -= 50  //Or 100, 200 as you required
             performAction()

        }
}



func performAction() {

        lastTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        otherTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    }
```

Comment: And don't forget to set `view.frame.origin.y = 0`  when resign last textField

Comment: I know this but I want keyboard size.
After that I can move up the view.
Thanks

Comment: Here instead of 50 how can I get keyboard size ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you are using autoLayout**

I am imagining all your `UITextField` to be present inside a separate `UIScrollView`. Further this `UISCrollView` will have a bottom constraint to its superView. Create an `IBOutlet` for this bottom spacing vertical constraint to its super view.

**Note:** You can do this even if its not inside a `UIScrollView` by simply taking the bottom constraint of your lowest `UITextField` but that will force your other `UITextFields` off screen so best put it inside a `UIScrollView`.

In your `viewDidLoad` setup observers as follows -

```
func viewDidLoad(){

    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

//and then:
//MARK: Animate Keyboard
func keyboardWillShow(notification : NSNotification){

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        animateKeyboard(withConstraintValue: keyboardSize.size.height)
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification : NSNotification){

    animateKeyboard(withConstraintValue: 0)
}

func animateKeyboard(withConstraintValue: CGFloat){

    scrollViewBottomSpaceConstraint.constant = withConstraintValue

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Comment: Actually I am not using scroll view.
My Requirement is I have to move the view up when l enter into last textField.

Everything is ok apart from this.

Comment: Please read the note :). I have added you can do the same thing as above by simply taking in the bottom constraint of the last `UITextField`!